# How to remove space between expanded ExpansionPanels in ExpansionPanelList?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

This is an example code for `ExpansionPanelList`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const MyStatefulWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// stores ExpansionPanel state information
class Item {
  Item({
    required this.expandedValue,
    required this.headerValue,
    this.isExpanded = false,
  });

  String expandedValue;
  String headerValue;
  bool isExpanded;
}

List<Item> generateItems(int numberOfItems) {
  return List<Item>.generate(numberOfItems, (int index) {
    return Item(
      headerValue: 'Panel $index',
      expandedValue: 'This is item number $index',
    );
  });
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  final List<Item> _data = generateItems(8);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        child: _buildPanel(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPanel() {
    return ExpansionPanelList(
      expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
        setState(() {
          _data[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded;
        });
      },
      children: _data.map<ExpansionPanel>((Item item) {
        return ExpansionPanel(
          headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(item.headerValue),
            );
          },
          body: ListTile(
              title: Text(item.expandedValue),
              subtitle:
                  const Text('To delete this panel, tap the trash can icon'),
              trailing: const Icon(Icons.delete),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  _data.removeWhere((Item currentItem) => item == currentItem);
                });
              }),
          isExpanded: item.isExpanded,
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

And it gives the following result:

[image]

As you see there is grey space between `Panel 0` and `Panel 1`, and between `Panel 1` and `Panel 2`. Could anyone say how to remove this space, if it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This space is added by `MaterialGap` inside source code.
[image]

```dart
if (_isChildExpanded(index) && index != 0 && !_isChildExpanded(index - 1))
   items.add(MaterialGap(
      key: _SaltedKey<BuildContext, int>(context, index * 2 - 1)));
```

You can  remove/comment this part or better create a local project file and comment this part.

To use your customized ExpansionPanelList, import your file like

```dart
import 'customized_expansionlist.dart' as customExp;
...

customExp.ExpansionPanelList(... customExp.ExpansionPanel(...))
```

Comment: I don't like this solution. Why is there no way to simply modify the behavior on the `ExpansionPanelList`. They messed up by not providing any option for that. Is there any way to simply hide all `MaterialGap` widgets in the entire tree?